# EF code-first, cannot delete foreign key relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a two models shown here:

```
public class Application
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<ApplicationTransaction> ApplicationTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ApplicationTransaction
{
  public long ApplicationId { get; set; }
  public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to delete all `ApplicationTransaction` of `Application` with this code:

```
var app = _repository.Get<Application>(i => i.Id == 1);
app.ApplicationTransactions.Clear();
Context.SaveChanges();
```

but when context goes to save the changes, an error occurs:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

[image]

Comment: models that show in code is different with db, i know it. i show brief of model

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and here's the solution:

Trick: When setting up the relationship between Parent and Child, you'll HAVE TO create a "composite" key on the child. This way, when you tell the Parent to delete 1 or all of its children, the related records will actually be deleted from the database.

To configure composite key using Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>.HasKey(t => new { t.ParentId, t.ChildId });
```

Then, to delete the related children:

```
var parent = _context.Parents.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ParentId == parentId);

var childToRemove = parent.Children.First(); // Change the logic 
parent.Children.Remove(childToRemove);

// or, you can delete all children 
// parent.Children.Clear();

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Just clearing the collection of related entities is not enough since each related entity stores a foreign key pointing to the `Application` entity; thus you need to delete related entities instead of clearing the collection of related entities.

```
foreach (ApplicationTransaction applicationTransaction in app.ApplicationTransactions.ToList())
    context.DeleteObject(applicationTransaction);
```

Comment: if an Application has thousand of Application Transaction, then EF must generate thousand query for each record.

Comment: @Behrooz Yes, but that's how it works. EF doesn't execute a one-shot delete when you clear a collection (as NHibernate can do). By the way, the DbContext syntax would be `context.ApplicationTransactions.Remove(applicationTransaction);

Comment: No, you'll have to set up a composite key on the children. This way, when you delete a child from its parent, EF will remove the relationship AND delete the child record from database. If you don't setup a composite key, it will only try to remove the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx) to create Relationship manually like this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Application>()
            .HasOptional(a => a.ApplicationTransactions)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(a => a.Application);
```

Then foreign Key columns will be nullable

Comment: i think WithOptionalPrincipal use for one-to-one elation, but this is one-to-many relation

Answer (score 0):

In your 'Save Application' Method you could have some logic like so:

```
var modifiedAppplicationTransactions = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<ApplicationTransactions>().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified);
foreach (var item in modifiedAppplicationTransactions )
{
    if (item.Entity.ApplicationId == null)
    {
        context.Entry(item.Entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
}
context.SaveChanges():
```